Numerically Convincing Evidence of Zero Eigenvalue
I am looking for applied numerical analysis tools/ideas to help me answer the following quite general problems. So this question might seem slightly off topic. Feel free to close it.
I have two known $d \times d$ real matrices $A$ and $B$, where $d$ is known. Denote the real part of eigenvalues of $A$ by $a_1, \ldots, a_d$ and the ones of $B$ by $b_1, \ldots, b_d$, ordered such that $a_1 \geqslant a_2 \geqslant \cdots \geqslant a_d$ and $b_1 \geqslant b_2 \geqslant \cdots \geqslant b_d$. Let us suppose also that I have theoretical results saying that $b_i \neq 0$ for every $i$ while there exists one $i \in \{1, \ldots, d\}$ such that $a_i = 0$. All I have to do now is to show that my theory works in a simulation.
Now in a numerical scenario, I have no choice but to compute all eigenvalues numerically. Let us say I get $\hat{a_i}$ and $\hat{b_i}$ as the numerical result for $a_i$ and $b_i$ respectively. Now as we would expect, we never actually arrive at a zero eigenvalue in matrix $A$ due to the fact that we have numerical methods. Although I do get exactly one $i$ such that $\hat{a_i}$ is quite close to zero, so close such that I would believe my theoretical belief is correct, is there any tool for me that helps me actually convince my readers that my theoretical belief is correct ?
More precisely, the nonzero $\hat{a_i}$'s range from $10^{9}$ to $10^3$ to $10^0$ to $-10^0$ to $-10^3$ to $-10^9$, the $i$ I suspect $a_i$ to be zero has $\hat{a_i}$ being around $10^{-10}$. The problem is that, $\hat{b_i}$'s range from $10^{9}$ to $10^3$ to $10^0$ to $-10^0$ to $-10^3$ to $-10^9$ also with very similar distributions and the minimum absolute value element to be around the order of $10^{-5}$. It sounds more or less arbitrary to just believe by this numerical evidence that my theory functions properly. But what can I do from now on ? The first thing I can think about is the determinant, which is not computable and even if it is there will not be a big difference. If I check the condition number, the two matrices have very similar condition number as the maximum and minimum eigenvalues have similar orders.

You should explore small perturbations of the matrix $A$. How much do you need to change the matrix $A$ before the perturbed matrix has a purely imaginary eigenvalue?
Let $\lambda$ be any complex number and let $x$ be any nonzero complex vector such that $Ax$ is defined. Let $r = \lambda x - Ax$ denote the corresponding residual. Let $\Delta A$ be given by $$\Delta A = \frac{1}{\|x\|_2^2}rx^*.$$ Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A+\Delta A$ corresponding to the eigenvector $x$ because $$(A + \Delta A)x = Ax + \Delta A x = Ax + r = Ax + \lambda x - Ax = \lambda x.$$
Now in your case, you have found an eigenvalue $\mu = a + ib$ with a tiny real part $a$ and I presume a corresponding eigenvector $x$? Then define $\lambda = ib$ and compute $r = \lambda x - Ax$. Compare a relevant norm of $\Delta A$ against the norm of $A$. If you only know $A$ with a relative error of $\tau$, then check if $$\|\Delta A \| \leq \tau \|A\|.$$ If yes, then it is at least not theoretically impossible that the true matrix $A$ has $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue. For the 2-norm, we have $$\|\Delta A\|_2 = \frac{\|r\|_2}{\|x\|_2}.$$
